# ForEach NavigationLink with State and Binding

Tags: ios, swift, binding, swiftui, property-wrapper

I'm trying to generate a ForEach with a NavigationLink and use State and Binding to pass some entity around:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    @FetchRequest(
        entity: MyEntity.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \MyEntity.name, ascending: true)
        ]

    ) var entries: FetchedResults<MyEntity>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(entries, id: \.self) { (entry: MyEntity) in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(myEntry: $entry)) {
                        Text(entry.name!)
                    }
                }.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then the following view:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var myEntry: MyEntity

    var body: some View {
        Text(myEntry.name!)
    }
}
```

The problem is I can not pass the value to Detail view since the error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier '$entry'
```

What is wrong here and how to solve this?

If I just have a simple `@State` its no problem to pass it via the binding, but I want/need to use it in the ForEach for the `FetchedResults`

EDIT: If I remove the `$` I get `Cannot convert value of type 'MyEntity' to expected argument type 'Binding<MyEntity>'`

EDIT2: The purpose is to pass some object to DetailView and then pass it back later to ContentView

Comment: check the type of entry which is provided in initialization closure by ForEach. Does MyEntity type provided its binding via its projectedValue property? That is what $ in front of entry means.

Comment: I can't understand. The MyEntity is a CoreData Element

Comment: If I remove the $ I get: Cannot convert value of type 'MyEntity' to expected argument type 'Binding<MyEntity>'

Comment: thats because you define it as parameter of DetailView. But MyEntity is not Binding<MyEntity>. with $entity compiler complain, because it doesn't exists. $ is shortcut to projectedValue, see property wrappers definition

Comment: So what I need to to since I not only need it in DetailView but I also need to pass is back later to ContentView

Comment: it is some reference type, so you can modify it, if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following in `ForEach`

```
   ForEach(entries, id: \.self) { entry in
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(myEntry: entry)) {
            Text(entry.name!)
        }
    }
```

and the following in `DetailView`

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var myEntry: MyEntity

    var body: some View {
        Text(myEntry.name!)
    }
}
```

The `MyEntity` is class, so you pass object by reference and changing it in `DetailView` you change same object.

Answer (score 1):

`FetchedResults<MyEntity> entities` does not conform to `Binding` or `DynamicProperty`. For the `$` symbol to workout must conform to `Binding`.

You can make a `FetchedResultsController` in an `ObservableObject` to get the same functionality as an `@FetchRequest`and have the ability to pass the values in an `EnvironmentObject` or `ObservedObject`.